# Is static assignment of Swing object OK?

Tags: java, swing, thread-safety, invokelater

For example: can this be used in a class MyPane?

```
public class MyPane extends JRootPane{
    public static JCheckBox Debug= new JCheckBox("Debug");
....
}
```

Will Swing have problem?  Should we always put these assignment in invokeLater?  Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want to use static anything in a Swing GUI? What would be your motivation for wanting to do this?

Comment: Swing won't have a problem with it, every body else might ...

Comment: @Mad: I don't agree. Swing in fact might have a problem with it, but I don't think that it can be 100% predicted if it will. It is always safest to create JComponents on the EDT.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oh, nice point!  Hadn't thought about the creation order of objects!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Basically I am trying to use a singleton.  I saw other people's code liek thsi too.  Fortunately, this is the only problem now.  I am going to put all these to singleton style and use invokeLater().

Comment: Don't use a singleton! (Regards class initialisation, it's probably going to be initialised by something else Swingy on the AWT EDT so will be okay, until a gnat sneezes.)